# How to ignore callback when im in interceptors in axios?

Tags: javascript, axios

I use axios interceptors to get the error. in some cases that I have error I do not want to return to the catch or then callback.

How I do it in axios? because if I dont return value it go to the `next`, but if I return `Promise.reject` it go to the `catch`.

I want when I have error in interceptors, not continue forward to the callback.

[codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-smoke-c01ue?file=/src/index.js:34-46)

```
import axios from "axios";

axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  (error) => {
    console.log({ error });

    // do not return to the catch/then in foo please! <-- HOW?

    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

const foo = () => {
  axios
    .post("https://httpstat.us/500")
    .then((r) => {
      console.log({ r });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log({ err });
    });
};

foo();
```

Comment: Why would you want to not go to the catch block? The whole point of promises is to be 'then'able and can be caught if there is an error. You don't have to use the .catch if you don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

you can return a resolve promises in the error function

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => response,
  (error) => {
    console.log({ error });

    return Promise.resolve();
  }
);
```

Comment: this will trigger the `then`